# How to get the sum of a numeric list from SharePoint?

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I'm retrieving numeric values from **SharePoint**. What I want to do is to add the values from list. However, I'm not sure how to get it while I call the column from SharePoint.

So far I have this:

```
//Column List from SharePoint which has a numeric value

if (item["ows_Amount_x0020__x0028_LC_x0029_"] != null)
{
  str.AppendLine("<td bgcolor='#FFFFFF';align='right';> " + Convert.ToDecimal(item["ows_Amount_x0020__x0028_LC_x0029_"]).ToString("N0") + "</td>");
}

//Location where I want to put in the Sum
str.AppendLine(" <tr style='color:#ffffff; font-weight:bold'><td bgcolor='#0096D6'>Forecast USD</td></tr>");
```

Comment: What does this code - if anything - when it is run?

Comment: @Brian it generates the data from the SP list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are looping through each item in the list it will look something like this since there is no support for aggregate functions like SUM with SPQuery.

```
double total = 0;
foreach(item in list){
  if(item["field"] == null)
     continue;

  total += item["field"];
  str.AppendLine("<td bgcolor='#FFFFFF';align='right';> " + Convert.ToDecimal(item["field"]).ToString("N0") + "</td>");
}
str.AppendLine(" <tr style='color:#ffffff; font-weight:bold'><td bgcolor='#0096D6'>Forecast USD:" + total.toString() + "</td></tr>");
```